# What are these data in light curve generator

Tags: magnitude, variable-star, light-curve

I'm generating light curves for some variable stars on the AAVSO website (see https://www.aavso.org/lcg ) . I can choose what type of data must be plotted. Can you explain what they are?

[image: The parameters.]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I was going to suggest "reading the manual", but I can't find one either! Would it have killed them to put a short description of the terms on dropdowns or pop-up boxes?

Comment: There is a manual but there isn't a parameters explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [file format](https://www.aavso.org/aavso-extended-file-format) for submitting observations to AAVSO sheds some light on this.

"Visual" data are estimates by visual comparison to nearby reference stars of similar brightness.

U, B, V, R, I data come from CCD cameras using standard filters in the Johnson-Cousins [photometric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometric_system), with passbands ranging from near ultraviolet to near infrared.
The J and H filters pass longer wavelengths in the infrared.

"Unfiltered w/(V|R) zero pt" are also from CCD cameras, not using one of the above filters, and calibrated using published V- or R-band magnitudes of reference stars.

Tri-R, Tri-G, Tri-B refer to the RGB channels of a color (e.g. consumer DSLR) camera.